# mysql server won't stop

Tags: mysql, linux, terminal, mamp

So I have tried countless things to try to stop MySQL from running.

I've tried to stop the process but it keeps giving me this error:

```
Executing '/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop' 2013-12-23 21:08:29 - 
Stop server: ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not 2013-12-23 21:08:29 - 
Stop server: be found!
```

[Here's a screenshot.](http://imageshack.us/a/img69/5515/dr1k.png)

I've also tried the following:

- Force Quitting
- Activity Monitor and Force Quitting the process
- Using the CLI / Terminal to Stop Process using:

  - killall -KILL Finder
  - killall -KILL Dock
  - killall -KILL SystemUIServer
  - killall -9 mysqld

result from last command:

```
~❯killall -9 mysqld
Password:
kill: kill 11963 failed: operation not permitted
~❯
```

and it still hasn't stopped running... unfortunately. I tried double checking with both the system preferences view as well as the mySQL workbench view. The system preferences says it's running. No response when I click stop. When I go to the workbench it says off and without me clicking "start" it just turns on.

So then I tried killing it and the results were as follows. Still hasn't stopped.. ugh..
(everything between the underscores below represents spacing)

```
~❯ps -A | grep mysql
11963 ?? _ _ _ _ . _ 0:01.27 --user=_mysql
14635 ttys000 _ _. _ 0:00:00 grep mysql
~❯sudo kill 11963
Password:
~❯
```

I then tried uninstalling all the MySQL files using the following commands:

```
- sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
- sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
- sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
- sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL*
- vim /etc/hostconfig and removed the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-
- rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/MySQL*
- sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
- sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
- sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
```

All to no avail.  Finally I thought if I maybe looked up all the files that had mysql in them and deleted the ones I was pretty sure were the right ones maybe this would work. So I used:

```
- sudo find / | grep -i mysql
```

Which showed all the files but still no luck.

Could anybody please help me figure this out?  I feel like I'm way overdoing this.

Comment: The PID file was probably deleted. The service command will not find what process to kill.

Comment: Try `sudo kill -9 11963`. BTW, did you try `sudo service mysqld stop` ?

Comment: Is this linux or osx? I am confused by the screenshot and the linux tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I GOT IT! :D

I ended up going back to the **activity monitor** and **searching for "mysql"** and then hitting **force quit** and it stopped it.  Although I had tried this previously and it did not work, for some reason it worked now.

I have Homebrew installed however I installed the mysql community server - Mac OS X 10.7 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive, yesterday.

I then used the command

sudo cp /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf /etc/my.cnf

to finish the job. I also have MAMP installed but I wanted to follow along in this class I'm taking so I went with what they were using.

On top of that I've been playing around with these alfred workflows and I found a couple that are really cool but I'm not going to use them anymore until I know more of what I'm doing because I think they are what screwed things up so bad.

Here are the links to them both though.  They basically allow you to start and stop your servers via alfred.  If you know what you are doing they can be a nice little time saver.

[Local Server Commands](https://github.com/m0nah/Alfred)

[Localhost (v1.1)](https://github.com/willfarrell/alfred-workflows)

Comment: Nice low-tech solution. I got so consumed with CLI commands I forgot about good old Activity Monitor

Answer (score 3):

How did you install MySQL? You can try any of the below options. It totally depends what mySQL packaged you installed.

**MacPorts**

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql.plist
Note: this is persistent after reboot.
```

**Homebrew**

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

**Binary installer**

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM restart
```